# How to compute disparity on a specific region of interest only?

Tags: stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is is possible, using stereo_image_proc, to compute disparities on a specific region of interest only?

The setup is as follow:

1. we detect a color blob in an image
2. we use stereo to determine its 3d position

It would greatly improve performances if we could just run the stereo on a subwindow. Is there a way to tell stereo_image_proc to do so?

We could probably just pass to stereo_image_proc a new pair of images matching the zone we want but it would be cumbersome to recompute the appropriate camera parameters and crop the images by hand...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30774/how-to-compute-disparity-on-a-specific-region-of-interest-only?/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK the parameter *roi* in CameraInfo.msg can be used to choose a region of interest. Try republishing a camera info with the roi set to your object region. And use that to feed stereo_image_proc. If you just need some sampled 3D points you should use [StereoCameraModel::projectDisparityTo3d](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1StereoCameraModel.html#afe8bf7a59e60f66cffb0ff03f7d30f9e). This is way faster than constructing a whole disparity image.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1